# How can i use the mouse wheel to select each time another Tool/s?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void OnEnable()
{
    Tools.current = Tool.View;
    Tools.viewTool = ViewTool.FPS;
}
```

The Tool have some properties like Rect,Scale,Rotate...
I want to use the mouse wheel up down to select between the Tool properties.

Comment: Do you have a Control where you want to use the mouswheel on?

Comment: And are u using a winform, wpf, uwp, etc. application or which type are u using?

Comment: Is this a Unity Plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really complicated.

**1**.Read mouse scroll input with [`Input.GetAxisRaw`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxisRaw.html) instead [`Input.GetAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) because using [`Input.GetAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) will smooth the scroll value over time which you don't need.

**2**.Check if the scroll value is more than some threshold value. If it is, then the mouse wheel is scrolling up. If it is less than that -value  then it is scrolling down.

**3**.From result **#2**, create a global integer called "level" you can increment or decrement depending on the direction of the scroll wheel.

**4**.The [Tool](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tool.html) enum values starts from `-1` to `4` because it is declared like this:

```
public enum Tool
{
    None = -1,
    View = 0,
    Move = 1,
    Rotate = 2,
    Scale = 3,
    Rect = 4
}
```

Clamp the "level" variable from **#3** to values between `-1` and `4` with [`Mathf.Clamp(level, -1, 4);`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html).

**5**.Finally, cast the int "level" variable to the [Tool](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tool.html) enum and assign the result to [`Tools.current`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tools-current.html).

The use of int to cast to [Tool](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tool.html) enum prevents the use of many if or switch statement.

```
float wheelThreshold = 0.09f;
int level = -1;

void Update()
{
    level = (int)Tools.current;

    float mouseScrollDir = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse ScrollWheel");

    if (mouseScrollDir > wheelThreshold)
    {
        Debug.Log("Scroll Up");
        level++;
        level = Mathf.Clamp(level, -1, 4);
        Tools.current = (Tool)level;
    }
    else if (mouseScrollDir < -wheelThreshold)
    {
        Debug.Log("Scroll Down");
        level--;
        level = Mathf.Clamp(level, -1, 4);
        Tools.current = (Tool)level;
    }
}
```

**Result**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are on an unity app, you can try this:

```
 var d = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
 if (d > 0f)
 {
     // scroll up
 }
 else if (d < 0f)
 {
     // scroll down
 }
```

[source](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/13485/implementing-the-scrollwheel.html)